# "When did you born?" or "When were you born?"

Tags: passive-voice, get-passive

Should I say "**When *did* you born?**" or "**When *were* you born?**"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"When were you born?"** is the correct version. A simple rule of thumb would be to replace it with a similarly formed verb. *Born* is past participle, so we could replace it with *written*.

**"When did you written?"** No. **"When were you written?"** Yes, if you were a book, and grammatically correct.

Comment: As an non-native English I fully understand the OP's confusion. Believe it or not, in many other languages people "bear themselves" (I am searching for the closest translation of the reflexive verb used for it in some languages) and not "are born" :)

Comment: What I think you mean is that in English birth is passive. So whilst we would say *I was born on a London bus*, in French they would say *Je suis né sur un autobus de Londres* which is active in exactly the same way as saying *Je suis allé au cinema*, meaning *I went to the cinema*. I understand your point.